# Yii2 Codeception basePath error

Tags: php, yii2, codeception

I've recently started to implement codeception testing in an existing Yii2 application.

The structure of tests has moved around greatly, but after creating a new project and using the default files in my existing app I am able to get tests to run. Unfortunately each test errors as follows:

```
6) HomeCest: Check open
 Test  tests/functional/HomeCest.php:checkOpen

  [yii\base\InvalidConfigException] The "basePath" property must be set.  


Scenario Steps:

 1. $I->amOnPage("/") at tests/functional/HomeCest.php:11

#1  /Users/rrbot/Sites/MYSITE/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php:222
#2  /Users/rrbot/Sites/MYSITE/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/View.php:150
#3  /Users/rrbot/Sites/MYSITE/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php:378
#4  /Users/rrbot/Sites/MYSITE/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php:114
#5  frontend\controllers\SiteController->actionIndex
#6  /Users/rrbot/Sites/MYSITE/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php:55
#7  /Users/rrbot/Sites/MYSITE/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php:154
#8  /Users/rrbot/Sites/MYSITE/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php:454
#9  /Users/rrbot/Sites/MYSITE/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php:100
#10 /Users/rrbot/Sites/MYSITE/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:315
```

My frontend/config/test-local.php looks as so:

```
<?php
// config/test-local.php
$config =  yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/main-local.php'),
    [
        'id' => 'app-tests',
        'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
        'components' => [
          'db' => [
              'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
              'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb',
              'username' => 'someser',
              'password' => 'somepass',
              'charset' => 'utf8',
          ],
        ]
    ]
);
return $config;
```

So as you can see, I am declaring the basePath, in fact re-declaring it as it is in the main.php as well.

Comment: Are you sure this is the test-local.php? (the comment says test.php).

Comment: Is Yii2 module of Codeception configured to use test-local.php? check configFile option.